# Testing for exceptions and catch exception details

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit

I've looked at other post concerning unit testing but none that I saw actually test what's in the exception when thrown. The main goal is to raise an exception and examine the details of the stack trace by sending a bad parameter to a helper class.

Since the original code wasn't throwing an exception I decided to do some online research on NUnit testing and come across a very nice piece of code that is lot shorter then what I wrote but failes to examine the error object. I need to be able to `Assert` a presence of certain verbiage in the stack trace.

Originally this is what the code looked like, but I must admit it is not very pretty:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestExceptionHandling()
    {
        try
        {
            DoExceptionScenario(new SomeCustomRadioButtonControl(), FieldManager.GetField("access_mode"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(CustomException), ex);
            string details = Util.GetExceptionDetails((CustomException)ex);
            Assert.IsTrue(details.Contains("Detail Name=\"ControlName\" Description=\"SomeCustomRadioButtonControl\""));
        }
    }
```

The problem as you may see is a possiblity of bunch of false positives.

The other way I modified the test is like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestExceptionHandling()
    {
        Assert.That(() => DoExceptionScenario(new SomeCustomRadioButtonControl(), FieldManager.GetField("access_mode")),
                Throws.TypeOf<CustomException>());
    }
```

This will fail if there is no exception. But if there is an exception how do I capture that and examine its contents? Something along lines of (the `if` statement would work in this case):

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldControlNameBeListedInStackTrace()
    {
        bool exceptionStatus = Assert.That(() => DoExceptionScenario(new SomeCustomRadioButtonControl(), FieldManager.GetField("access_mode")),
                Throws.TypeOf<CustomException>());

        if (exceptionStatus != true)
        {
            string details = Util.GetExceptionDetails((CustomException)ex);
            Assert.IsTrue(details.Contains("detail name=\"controlname\" description=\"SomeCustomRadioButtonControl\""));            
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume a `CustomException` class that looks like this. It doesn't do much of anything... just overrides the "Message" property from the base `Exception` class:

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    private string message;

    public override string Message
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, message); }
    }

    public CustomException(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And assume you have a method that throws the exception, such as this:

```
public class ProductionClass
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new CustomException("Oh noz!");
    }
}
```

Here's a few sample tests you can use in nUnit. You want the last one.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTests
{
    private ProductionClass p;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        p = new ProductionClass();
    }

    // Use the ExpectedException attribute to make sure it threw.
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(CustomException)]
    public void Test1()
    {
        p.SomeMethod();
    }

    // Set the ExpectedMessage param to test for a specific message.
    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(CustomException), ExpectedMessage = "Oh nozzzz!")]
    public void Test2()
    {
        p.SomeMethod();
    }

    // For even more detail, like inspecting the Stack Trace, use Assert.Throws<T>.
    [Test]
    public void Test3()
    {
        var ex = Assert.Throws<CustomException>(() => p.SomeMethod());

        Assert.IsTrue(ex.StackTrace.Contains("Some expected text"));
    }
}
```

The [`Assert.Throws<T>`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5) method works with any `Exception`. It executes the delegate in the parentheses and detects whether or not it threw the exception.

In the above test, if it *did* throw, it then tests the stack trace for the specified contents too. If both steps pass, the test passes.